# Как написать скрипт, который автоматически добавит человеку приглашение в онлайн-календарь

Tags: javascript, google-calendar

Я работаю в онлайн-школе. У нас каждый месяц проводятся live-вебинары.
Мне как прожекту подкинули задачу: хотим, чтобы после того как клиент оставил заявку на лендинге веба (Тильда), ему в календарь (привязанный к оставленной почте...можно начать с Google) автоматически приходило приглашение на событие.

**Нужен скрипт** (или альтернативное решение), который сможет делать так:

- Человек на лендинге оставил заявку: имя, телефон, почту
- Заявка отправилась к нам в базу
- Человеку сразу же пришло приглашение на мероприятие в календарь

Наш парт-тайм разраб не знает, как это можно организовать, пришла за советом, возможно ли это вообще сделать :3 Skyeng так делал, но хз, как и чем

Спасибо!

Comment: Вот api гугл календаря https://developers.google.com/calendar/, скиньте разрабу - пусть разбирается ))

Comment: Можно создать гугл календарь и скидывать его